# What is this Mac OS X app running on my menu bar (three right arrows icon)?

Tags: macos

Below is the app and it's menu items. I have no idea what it is. And there's no name anywhere. If this is a real app, I would be amazed at the UI for being so dumb. It's a Mac OS X app and it starts when I boot the computer. I looked at my startup items but cant tell which app it is because there's no name anywhere on the menu. I also tried leaving mouse to see if tooltip shows up. NOPE.

Is this a trojan?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some computer management tool by [LANDesk](http://landesk.com/) (compare the company logo).

Comment: Thanks! Man what a stupid UI for not letting me know what the hell it is.